# What software is used to draw 3D geometrical figures like this

Tags: geometry

I was wondering what software they were using to draw figures like this, I often see this kind of figures with the same colors on wikipedia do they have a particular software that they use for these?

[from wikipedia]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a49GW.gif

another example (I couldn't upload) https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2d/BoysSurfaceTopView.PNG/330px-BoysSurfaceTopView.PNG

I've done my research and found grapher which seemed good (different from the picture I posted though) but it's only available on Mac.

Comment: That's the default 3D rendering style of Mathematica (before they changed it in v10).

Comment: @Rahul Thanks I'm gonna look into it

Comment: As Rahul said,  this looks like Mathematica. However,  you can get similar plots in Matlab,  Julia or R.

Comment: It could have been done in Maple.